# how to scroll to the selected row in gridview using Asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, gridview

I am working with ASP.net and C#

I have a GridView with Multiple rows. I have a text box and search button. My grid columns are Id and name. If I type a name in the text box and click search button. I have highlighted the names in the grid which I typed in the textbox and must scroll to the highlighted row.

How can I search and Highlight it but cannot scroll to the selected row?

Comment: can you show us some code you made so far?

Comment: Do you have unique ID for each row in GridView  ??

Comment: Yes i have a primary key for Id

Comment: An example by using Jquery can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6677035/jquery-scroll-to-element

Comment: no that's not working it just moving the scroll from last to top. I need to scroll to the position which i specify in the text box

Answer (score 0):

Try below function

```
function scrollToElement(selector, time, verticalOffset) {
time = typeof(time) != 'undefined' ? time : 500;
verticalOffset = typeof(verticalOffset) != 'undefined' ? verticalOffset : 0;
element = $(selector);
offset = element.offset();
offsetTop = offset.top + verticalOffset;
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: offsetTop
}, time);
}
```

Call this function like `` scrollToElement('elementUniqueIdHere`,  750, -50); ``

Hope this helps you.